# NoClassDefFoundError: Tests fail during Maven test phase when SureFire forkCount is greater than 0

Tags: junit4, java-9, spring-test, maven-surefire-plugin, springrunner

**Issue**

Java 9 / Java 10 Module Mode: Tests failing due to initializationError: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner` when SureFire `forkCount` > 0

- Spring Boot: 2.0.1.RELEASE
- Java: "10" 2018-03-20 (Vendor: Oracle Corporation)
- Maven: 3.5.3
- maven-compiler-plugin: 3.7.0
- maven-surefire-plugin: 2.21.0
- macOS: 10.12.6

**Relevant stack trace**

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.21.0:test (default-test) @ turbo ---
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.axiom.turbo.UserControllerIntegrationTest
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.axiom.turbo.UserControllerIntegrationTest
[ERROR] initializationError(com.axiom.turbo.UserControllerIntegrationTest)  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:379)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:340)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:413)
```

**Relevant section of pom.xml**

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <release>${java.version}</release>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.21.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <forkCount>1</forkCount> <!-- works if set to 0 -->
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

If the `forkCount` is 0 then the tests pass and the build succeeds. It appears that SureFire fails on forking the Java process. Is this a known issue?

Comment: [JUnit tests pass in Eclipse but fail in Maven Surefire](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3365628/1278112) seems like it is.